# stanford-segmenter-2015-12-09 crash

Tags: stanford-nlp

The new stanford-segmenter-2015-12-09 crashes on the Ubuntu 14.04 64-bit with OpenJDK:

```
tahoar@library0:~$ java -version
java version "1.7.0_91"
OpenJDK Runtime Environment (IcedTea 2.6.3) (7u91-2.6.3-0ubuntu0.14.04.1)
OpenJDK 64-Bit Server VM (build 24.91-b01, mixed mode)
```

Here's the output of the sample script:

```
./segment.sh ctb test.simp.utf8 UTF-8 0

(CTB):
File: test.simp.utf8
Encoding: UTF-8
-------------------------------
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.UnsupportedClassVersionError: edu/stanford/nlp/ie/crf/CRFClassifier : Unsupported major.minor version 52.0
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.defineClass1(Native Method)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.defineClass(ClassLoader.java:800)
    at java.security.SecureClassLoader.defineClass(SecureClassLoader.java:142)
    at java.net.URLClassLoader.defineClass(URLClassLoader.java:449)
    at java.net.URLClassLoader.access$100(URLClassLoader.java:71)
    at java.net.URLClassLoader$1.run(URLClassLoader.java:361)
    at java.net.URLClassLoader$1.run(URLClassLoader.java:355)
    at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
    at java.net.URLClassLoader.findClass(URLClassLoader.java:354)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:425)
    at sun.misc.Launcher$AppClassLoader.loadClass(Launcher.java:308)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:358)
    at sun.launcher.LauncherHelper.checkAndLoadMain(LauncherHelper.java:482)
```

On Windows 10 with Oracle Java, it runs fine:

```
C:\Users\tahoar>java -version
java version "1.8.0_66"
Java(TM) SE Runtime Environment (build 1.8.0_66-b18)
Java HotSpot(TM) Client VM (build 25.66-b18, mixed mode, sharing)
```

Any suggestions for JRE for Linux?

Comment: You're using code compiled for Java 1.8 and running it on Java 1.7.

Comment: DOH! The Stanford Segmenter home page says, "The system requires Java 1.8+ to be installed." My bad!